# hibernate logging can't stop it

Tags: java, hibernate, log4j

I've tried I think all the info I've found in the Internet, with no results. I want to switch off the Hibernate Logging.

My log4j.properties:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate = INFO
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=INFO, SQL_APPENDER
log4j.additivity.org.hibernate.SQL=false
log4j.rootLogger=INFO
```

My log4.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true"
                     xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>
<logger name="org.hibernate">
  <level value="info"/> 
</logger>
   <appender name="consoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1} - %m%n"/>
      </layout>
   </appender>

   <appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="append" value="false"/>
      <param name="file" value="out/learning.log"/>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
      </layout>
   </appender>

   <root>
      <level value="INFO"/>
      <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
      <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>
   </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Inside my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">false</property>
```

At this moment I don't know what else can I do to stop those disturbing messages on my console.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hibernate uses slf4j for logging, what slf4j jars are on your classpath? Also why do you have 2 log4j config files?

Comment: log4j-1.2.15.jar, slf4j-api-1.5.3.jar, slf4j-log4j12-1.5.3.jar and slf4-simple-1.4.2.jar. Well, I've got two files because I don't know which one is the valid one. How to define which one do I have to use?

Answer (score 0):

try to use **OFF** level for each appender might help

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Level.html

Comment: Well, that was the first thing I tried, with no result. At the moment I'm setting the appenders to INFO, but it also throws the lines with DEBUG, so there must be something I'm doing wrong. :-(

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage you to read the [SLF4J Manual](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html), you should only have 1 Binding jar on your classpath.

Remove `slf4-simple-1.4.2.jar` from your classpath, it may be stopping log4j being used.

> ***slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar***
>
> Binding for Simple implementation, which outputs all events to System.err. Only messages of level INFO and
> higher are printed. This binding may be useful in the context of small
> applications.

Comment: Well. In fact I don't need that lib, so I've eliminated it from my lib pot, but anyway it doesn't fix the problem. I still get all the debug messages in my console :-(